# Why didn't my question show up in the active questions list?

Tags: support, questions

I just posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18626146/qmake-moc-files-confused-by-namespaces) - but at the (seemingly) exact moment I posted it, the site crashed and then came back on (or at least the StackExchange blog crashed, I didn't test other pages before it came back online).

Normally when I ask a question, it appears in the 'questions' list. This time it did not.
It doesn't show up (at least not for me) in any of the lists associated with the tags I tagged the question with.

Now I'm not sure if I should delete the question and repost it (which is against many sites' rules, often called 'shadow bumping'), or what else to do.

It's only been viewed twice - both by me, afaik. If it's not listed anywhere, how can anyone see and answer it? =(...

Comment: I see it in all locations you tagged.

Comment: Uh, I can't see this meta question either. New theory: Users can't see their own questions? =P Thought I've seen my own questions in those lists before! Maybe I was just imagining it.

Comment: try a different browser to see if it's a cache issue.  > New theory: Users can't see their own questions?  Oh, wait, right! maybe it's that new "Read Protected" flag :-O

Comment: New new theory: I'm just being stupid and had it on the wrong tab. I guess I had it on 'interesting' or 'frequent' or something else, instead of 'newest'. Thanks for your [help/patience/tolerance-of-stupidity].

Comment: DOH ! You need a new, SE-geeky bumper sticker: Tabs Happen!

Comment: Yep! I checked the tabs too, having seen and read the question I just marked this as a duplicate of, but I got confused by how the second layer of tabs change depending on the selection of the first layer of tabs. =/

Comment: Kudo's for "self-flagging" your own post as a duplicate... wonder if there's a badge for that ? LOL